# Dependency inversion - owner of interfaces?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I am starting with ASP.NET MVC and trying to learn DI and dependency inversion at the same time. I am setting up at MVC project where the controllers and views reside in one assembly and I also have a couple of more assemblies for domain models and services that to most of the actual business logic.

The plan is to have all my services implement interfaces. The controllers that call the services access them through these interfaces. Instantiation is done using the Ninject DI framework.

Now the actual question; who "owns" the interfaces? From my understanding of dependency inversion, the service interfaces would be owned by the controllers and therefore reside in that assembly.

Comment: Why don't use a separate assembly for "extensibility" to contain interfaces ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731515/dependency-injection-who-owns-the-interface

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401466/how-to-structure-interfaces-in-application-directory-hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your components have to *own* the interfaces. Good interfaces are their own animal - they just have to be visible to both the controllers and services.

Physically segregating them [creates headaches that may be unnecessary](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ControllingDependencies) - I recommend that you do not use multiple assemblies without a good reason.

Comment: My understanding of dependency inversion; with "normal" dependencies, lower level components specify their features and the higher level components depend on these specifications. With inverted dependencies, the higher level components specify what the need from the lower level components, ie the interfaces they need to implement. That would mean that the higher level components "own" the interfaces. Does that make sense? Of course, this doesn't have to mean that the interfaces must reside in the same assembly/module/whatever as the higher level components.

Comment: I suppose I don't really understand what you mean by 'own' here. When would ownership matter? Well-designed interfaces often end up being used by multiple consumers, in which case the don't have a single owner.

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces must be visible to the implementors. The implementation may be visible to consumers. If you want to separate the implementation from interface such that they can be deployed separately, then the interfaces should reside in their own assembly.

If you are disciplined enough to organize your code based on namespaces and have no special deployment requirements, the interfaces can reside in the same assembly as the implementation.

Comment: Virtual -1. "The implementation may be visible to consumers." -> Wrong

Comment: Yes it may be. There is no rule carved in stone that says you MUST separate interfaces and impls in different deployment artefact, or that your impls MUST be internal or otherwise hidden. That's why I say discipline. You can enable DI wo/ problems and have impls and interface in the same assembly. It all depends on your deployment needs. I have this issue with customers ALL the time. Projects are Deployment artefacts, not a code organization and quality enabler.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces to services (normally provide data and implemented as WCF) need to reside on a separate DLL and MVC will have a reference to.

So here is a typical (and basic) splitting of the classes and interfaces into projects (and assemblies):

- Common
- Entity (reference Common)
- Service Interface (reference Common and Entity)
- Service Implementation (reference all above)
- Presentation (References all above but Implementation) and has WCF procies, view specific logic
- MVC project (references all above but Implementation)